# Deadlock because of update query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 18 million rows. It has 2 indexes. One clustered index with primary key and another non clustered index with 3 columns namely A,B and C.

Scenario :
A windows service polls 16 rows from this table every 100 milliseconds and creates web service request for each of the rows and sends to the web service. The web service sends the response for each request and windows service then updates the table with the response data based on the columns A,B and C(combination of A,B and C columns make a row unique).

This works fine when the number of rows is around 100k. 
But results in deadlock on the table where row volume is 18 million.

What can be the reason? 
The env with 18 million rows is unaccessible. But we got the profiler trace though which shows Update query deadlocking on itself because it acquires page locks instead of row locks.

Comment: You should read about "Lock Escalation", I think you will find an answer there.

Comment: @Denis Rubashkin This is not lock escalation (that goes from row to table or from page to table, and never from row to page), that is just another lock granularity

Comment: What does the update query actually do? Presumably it does not just perform a single `UPDATE` or else a deadlock would not occur. Is it performing a `SELECT` prior to the `UPDATE` - could this be removed?

Comment: @sepupic When locking rows or index key ranges, the Database Engine places an intent lock on the pages that contain the rows or keys.(с)technet.microsoft.com

Comment: @Denis Rubashkin >>>When locking rows or index key ranges, the Database Engine places an intent lock on the pages that contain the rows or keys<<< And what? Did I say it doesn't? What I said instead that in OP's case there is NO lock escalation. He says, he has *page* locks, *not a table lock*. There was NO lock escalation in his case

Comment: It has 3 queries. One is for updating a table. Second is for deleting from another table and third is for inserting into the table from which second query is deleting.